# Understanding the derivation of equation of motion in rotating frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

[image]

> Next, we consider how the change of *any* vector during a small time-interval $\Delta t$ can be expressed as the vector sum of two contributions:
>
> 1. The change that would occur if it were simply a vector of constant length embedded in the rotating frame $S'\;.$
> 2. The further change described by its change of length and direction as observed in $S'\;.$
>
> The vector $\bf A$ at time $t$ is represented by $CD\;.$ If it remains fixed with respect to a rotating table, its direction at time $t+\Delta t$ is given by the line $CE\;,$ where $\Delta \theta = \omega\Delta t\;.$ Thus its change due to rotation alone would be represented by $DE\,,$ where $DE= A\Delta \theta= A\omega\Delta \theta\;.$ From the standpoint of frame $S'$ this change would not be observed. There might, however, be a change represented by the line $EF\;;$ we shall denote this as $\Delta \mathbf A_{S'}$- the change of $\bf A$ as observed in $S'\;.$ **The vector sum of$DE$ and $EF\,,$ i.e., the line $DF\,,$ then represents the true change of $\bf A$ as observed in $S\;.$** We therefore denote as $\Delta \mathbf A_S\;.$
>
> [...]  Thus we have $$\Delta \mathbf A_S= \Delta \mathbf A_{S'}+ (\omega\times \mathbf A)\,\Delta t\;.$$ ...

This is excerpted from *A.P.French*'s *Newtonian Mechanics*.

I'm having problem in conceiving the bold line above in the quoted stanza.

$\Delta A_{S'},$ the change in $\bf A$ in $\Delta t$ can only be witnessed in the rotating frame $S'$ as is evident in the author's words "*the change of $\bf A$ as observed in $S'\;.$*"

How can the same change be witnessed in the inertial frame $S\;?$

Why does the true change in $\bf A$ as seen in $S$ need to consider the exact change $\Delta A_{S'}$ as seen in $S'\;?$ After-all what is the guarantee that there would be same deflection of the moving particle in the inertial frame $S$ as seen in $S'\;?$

If $\Delta A_{S'}$ constitute the *true change* as conceived in the inertial frame $S\,,$ then how can the same $\Delta A_{S'}$ be viewed in $S'$- what would then the difference between $S$ and $S'$ remain if the change in $\bf A$ is same in both frames of reference?

What is the motivation behind adding $\Delta A_{S'}$ to get the the total *true change* of $\bf A$ in $S\,?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are riding along the rigid body, the vector $\boldsymbol{A}$ is not fixed. It may change with time and you see this change as $\Delta \boldsymbol{A}_{S'}$.

Now to find the change in $\boldsymbol{A}$ from an inertial (non-rotating) frame you have to add the effect of the rotation as the unit vectors of the S' coordinate frame change. This is the $(\boldsymbol{\omega} \Delta t) \times \boldsymbol{A}$ part.

Comment: Got the point; One more thing, I would like to know: French pointed out two changes of a vector in the rotating frame $S'\;;$ can you point me out what these changes are in $\bf A\;?$

Comment: Changes in magnitude and/or direction. Either one has to be accounted for.